# Make two values from one implode variable with PHP

Tags: php

I have created a form that allows a user to tick a checkbox and when the user posts the form I want to somehow split the value of the checkbox after the '-' symbol and insert both values into two separate columns.

The form on page 1:

```
<form method="post" action="scripts/add-users-to-courses.php">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td><strong>Course Name</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Username</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Add User to Course</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
            foreach($course_array as $coursetitle) {
                foreach($user_array as $username) {
                    echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'. $coursetitle .'</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $username .'</td>';
                        echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="course" value="'. $coursetitle .'-'. $username .'"></td>';
                    echo '</tr>';
                }
            }
        ?>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="<?php echo $btn_custom; ?>">
</form>
```

The insert statement (form action):

```
<?php
    require '../manager-session.php';
    require '../../db-config.php';
    include '../../distributor-config.php';

    if(isset($_POST['course'])) {
        $selected = explode(',', $_POST['course']);
        $coursetitle = $selected[0];
        $username = $selected[1];

        echo 'Selected: '. $selected .'';
        echo 'Course Title: '. $coursetitle .'';
        echo 'Username: '. $username .'';

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users_on_courses (useroncourse, course) VALUES (?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $coursetitle);
        $stmt->execute();

        header('location: ../add-users-to-courses.php?page=add-users-to-courses&status=success');
        exit();
    }

    else {
        header('location: ../add-users-to-courses.php?page=add-users-to-courses&status=error');
        exit();
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
?>
```

At the moment, $selected is equal to 'Course Name - Username'. I am trying to insert the Course Name in to the course column and then obviously the username in the useroncourse column.

Is it possible to do this in the way I have started?

Comment: If you just want to separate `Course Name - Username'` by `-` then use `explode("-", "Course Name - Username'")` and it will return an array of individual values.

Comment: @FrayneKonok You must use `trim()` also then. Plus it doesn't work when the Course Name is `Sports - and - Fitness - StudentName`

Answer (score 0):

You should use **explode()**

**Example -**

```
$selected = explode('-', $_POST['course']);
$courseName = $selected[0];
$username = $selected[1];
```

Then you can store these variables into db.

Comment: Please explain why he should use explode and why it's better than other methods. You also forgot the blankspace on right and left side ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode:

```
    <?php
    require '../manager-session.php';
    require '../../db-config.php';
    include '../../distributor-config.php';

    if(isset($_POST['course'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['course'] as $course) {
            $selected = explode(',', $course);
            $courseTitle = $selected[0];
            $username = $selected[1];
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users_on_courses (useroncourse, course) VALUES (:userOnCourse, :username)");
            $stmt->bind_param("userOnCourse", $courseTitle);
            $stmt->bind_param("username", $username);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }

?>
```

When you use an input field with this `name="names[]"` the result you get in server side will be an array. So if you use `name="course"` you are getting an array with the selected courses.

Comment: PHP Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in...

Comment: I have updated my code but don't get two separate values still? See above.

Comment: The code I wrote is for 1 course. You have several courses

Comment: I got it working with one course, how would one go about doing it for multiple users and courses?

Comment: it seems to only insert the last user? For example if I select user1, user2, user3, user4, it will only insert the data of user4.

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="course" value="'. $coursetitle .'-'. $username .'"> only.

Comment: The error is: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: For several values you need to use `name="course[]"`

Comment: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in

Comment: that seems to contain it all in a long string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126630/discussion-between-sebcar-and-user6618037).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `explode(' - ', $courseValue);` but it might fail when the course name or the students name contains also `-`.

You could use a regex pattern similiar to `/^(\w)[\s+]-[\s+](\w)$/i` but its not safe either.

I suggest you this third option.

Seperate the values form beginning on.

```
<input type="checkbox"
       name="course[]"
       value="'. $coursetitle .' - '. $username .'"
       data-course="' . $coursetitle . '"
       data-user="' . $username . '">
```

Now use DOM selector to fetch the `data` attributes and submit this form using Ajax.

This is also best practice. You don't want to merge already seperated, structured data and extract it afterwards with a risk of failure.

Comment: `[\s+]` is more simply expressed as `\s+`.